# Implementing inheritance overriding the toString method

Tags: java

I have created a (Person,Student,Employee,Faculty and Staff)classes. Person has to subclasses Student and Employee. 
Employee has two subclasses Faculty and Staff. I have done all the codings an they are working fine except my **driver class** ***TestPerson program*** its giving compilation errors

Note: A test program that Creates a Person,Student,Employee,Faculty,Staff, and invokes their toString Method.

The errors of driver class **TestPerson.java** are below:-

```
 
error: constructor Student in class Student cannot be applied to given types;
error: no suitable constructor found for Employee(String,String,String,String)
error: constructor Faculty in class Faculty cannot be applied to given types;
error: no suitable constructor found for Staff(String,String,String,String)"
```

**I am just providing the codes of the driver class. If you need my other codings of the other classes, please state in the comment, and I will immediately post it.

Please see my codings below:-

```
public class TestPerson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("John Doe", "123 Somewhere", "415-555-1212", "johndoe@somewhere.com");
        Person student = new Student("Mary Jane", "555 School Street", "650-555-1212", "mj@abc.com", "junior");
        Person employee = new Employee("Tom Jones", "777 B Street", "40-88-889-999", "tj@xyz.com");
        Person faculty = new Faculty("Jill Johnson", "999 Park Ave", "92-52-22-3-333", "jj@abcxyz.com");
        Person staff = new Staff("Jack Box", "21 Jump Street", "707-21-2112", "jib@jack.com");

        System.out.println(person.toString() + "\n");
        System.out.println(student.toString() + "\n");
        System.out.println(employee.toString() + "\n");
        System.out.println(faculty.toString() + "\n");
        System.out.println(staff.toString() + "\n");
        }
}
```

//Person Class

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone_number;
    private String email_address;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String newName, String newAddress, String newPhone_number, String newEmail){
        name = newName;
        address = newAddress;
        phone_number = newPhone_number;
        email_address = newEmail;
    }

    public void setName(String newName){
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String newAddress){
        address = newAddress;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public void setPhone(String newPhone_number){
        phone_number = newPhone_number;
    }

    public String getPhone(){
        return phone_number;
    }

    public void setEmail(String newEmail){
        email_address = newEmail;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email_address;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Name :"+getName();
    }

}
```

//Student class

```
public class Student extends Person {

    public final String class_status;

    public Student(String name, String address, int phone, String email, String classStatus) {
    super(name, address, phone, email);
    class_status = classStatus;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Student Status: " + super.getName();
    }

}
```

//Employee Class

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Employee extends Person{

    private String office;
    private double salary;
    private Date hire;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String name, String address, int phone, String email){
        super(name, address, phone, email);
    }

    public Employee(String office, double salary, Date hire){
        this.office = office;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.hire = hire;
    }

    public void setOffice(String office){
        this.office = office;
    }

    public String getOffice(){
        return this.office;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary){
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double getSalary(){
        return this.salary;
    }

    public void setHire(Date hire){
        this.hire = hire;
    }

    public Date getHire(){
        return this.hire;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Office " + super.getName();
    }
}
```

//Faculty Class

```
public class Faculty extends Employee {
    private String officeHours;
    private int rank;

    public Faculty(String name, String address, int phone, String email) {
    super(name, address, phone, email);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Office " + super.getOffice();
    }
}
```

//Staff Class

```
public class Staff extends Employee {
    private String title;

    public Staff(String name, String address, int phone, String email) {
    super(name, address, phone, email);
    }

    public Staff(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Title :" + super.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to post the constructors for those classes.

Comment: The error is not at `tostring`. You are calling constructors which don't exist.

Comment: Ok I am posting my other classes coding now:-

Comment: You should avoid using `int` to reference phone numbers.  Use a `String`, or even better, a specific phone number class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting those errors is that the constructors don't exist.

> error: constructor Student in class Student cannot be applied to given
>   types; error: no suitable constructor found for
>   Employee(String,String,String,String)

That means you will not get the code to compile until you have this:

```
Student(String name, String addr, String phone, String email) {
    ....
}
```

Assuming you have set the properties in the constructor, toString would look like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.name + "\n" + this.addr + "\n" + this.phone + "\n" + this.email;

}
```

**UPDATE**

Your problem is that Student has only this constructor:

```
public Student(String name, String address, int phone, String email, String classStatus)
```

Student needs a constructor which takes only four strings as its parameters. Alternatively, you can make everything take the five parameters you specified.

Comment: Yess...it worked.,. Me so stupid...i put the variable int and then try to get the output as a String....Thanks Mike...really appriciate it

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when you see errors like that, pay VERY close attention to the parameters you are passing. Either the method doesn't exist at all or the parameters are wrong somehow.

Answer (score 2):

It's perhaps not related to the question itself, but I think the design could be refined like this:

- define abstract class Role with the name of role
- define classes Student, Employee, Staff whatever inheriting Role
- define class Person with common properties for all person type, names etc, and having property of type Role inside

then define toString on Person and in all Role implementation

in this way you will be able to extend or modify Persons independently from Roles, which makes the design more flexible

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of Person requires a String as third argument, but you are trying to pass `int phone` to the super-constructor in your sub-classes. That won't work because it's the wrong type.

By the way: you should always represent phone numbers with strings, not with integers.

1. It doesn't make sense to add or subtract phone numbers.
2. Integers don't allow leading zeros, which are used for area codes in some
   countries.
3. Integers can't be larger than 2147483648. When you
   try to store very long telephone numbers, this seemingly arbitrary
   limit will cause very unexpected bugs.

Comment: No. I would really implement phone numbers with a phone number type. You can't concatenate phone numbers, nor perform upper/lower case operations or similar. You can't validate their construction implicitly if they're strings etc.

Comment: Well, concatenation of phone numbers can make sense when you have special handling of area codes or extensions. The most clean way would be to create a PhoneNumber class which checks input to be a valid phone number and automatically discards dashes or whitespaces which some people arbitrarily add to phone numbers for readability. But in most cases that would be over-engineering. And wouldn't you use a String to store the number internally anyway?

Answer (score 1):

First Set the Phone Number datatype as integer in all the classes ..

main Function will be:

```
public class TestPerson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("John Doe", "123 Somewhere", "415-555-1212",
                                   "johndoe@somewhere.com");
        Person student = new Student("Mary Jane", "555 School Street", 
                                     650-555-1212, "mj@abc.com", "junior");
        Person employee = new Employee("Tom Jones", "777 B Street", 
                                       40-88-889-999,  "tj@xyz.com");
        Person faculty = new Faculty("Jill Johnson", "999 Park Ave",
                                     92-52-22-3-333, "jj@abcxyz.com");
        Person staff = new Staff("Jack Box", "21 Jump Street", 707-21-2112, 
                                 "jib@jack.com");

        System.out.println(person.toString() + "\n");
        System.out.println(student.toString() + "\n");
        System.out.println(employee.toString() + "\n");
        System.out.println(faculty.toString() + "\n");
        System.out.println(staff.toString() + "\n");
    }
}
```